# How to rotate a computer drawing in 90 degrees

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I have created a bunny and a duck image in my blank window. My plan was to display it twice: once by itself and another image like it rotated at a 90 degrees. I've tried creating the image a second time and turning the image by changing values, but was difficult and couldn't work at all. Which axes needs to be used to rotate an image in a plane and the right way to accomplish it.

```
void myInit(void){
        glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0);  // the background is white
        glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  // set drawing color
        gluOrtho2D(0.0, (GLdouble) screenWidth, 0.0, (GLdouble) screenHeight);
    }

void drawBunny(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // draw the outline of box (bunny)
    glLineWidth(2);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        glVertex2i(50,50);
        glVertex2i(150,50);
        glVertex2i(150,100);
        glVertex2i(50,100);

    glEnd();

    //draw bunny tail
    glLineWidth(1);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
     glVertex2i(50,50);
     glVertex2i(50,35);//2nd wider top/bottom
     glVertex2i(70,35);//1st- shrink tail left/right
    glVertex2i(70,50);//1st- shrink tail left/right
    glEnd();

    // draw first ear
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        glVertex2i(175,85);
        glVertex2i(175,100);
        glVertex2i(150,100);
        glVertex2i(150,85);
    glEnd();

    //draw second ear
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        glVertex2i(175,70);
        glVertex2i(175,100);
        glVertex2i(150,100);
        glVertex2i(150,70);
    glEnd();

    // draw the head
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        glVertex2i(150,100);
        glVertex2i(150,110);
        glVertex2i(125,110);
        glVertex2i(125,100);
    glEnd();

    // draw first feet
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        glVertex2i(110,60);
        glVertex2i(110,75);
        glVertex2i(30,75); //decrease value increase feet
        glVertex2i(30,60);
    glEnd();

    //draw second feet
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        glVertex2i(50,100);
        glVertex2i(50,85);
        glVertex2i(30,85); //decrease value increase feet
        glVertex2i(30,100);
    glEnd();

     //* draw eyes
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        glVertex2i(140,100);
        glVertex2i(140,105);
        glVertex2i(135,105);
        glVertex2i(135,100);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

int main (int argc, char** argv){
    glutInit(&argc, argv);  // initialize the toolkit
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);  // set display mode
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,150);  // set window position
    glutInitWindowSize(screenWidth,screenHeight); // set window size
    glutCreateWindow("House");  // create & open window
    glutDisplayFunc(drawBunny);  // register redraw function
    myInit();
    glutMainLoop();  // loop forever
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write a display function which consist of 2 bunnies and rotate them :

```
void display()
{
    glLoadIdentity();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    drawBunny();

    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(degreetoreturn,x,y,z); // Adjust parameters according to what you need
    drawBunny();
    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();

}
```

Delete `glClear()` function and `glFlush()` functions from your drawBunny function. And finally in your main function change this line :

```
glutDisplayFunc(drawBunny);  // register redraw function
```

to

```
glutDisplayFunc(display);  // register redraw function
```

Comment: **+1** - One minor point however: `glutSwapBuffers (...)` isn't correct in this scenario. The pixel format is single-buffered. While I wouldn't suggest using a single-buffered pixel format (`GLUT_SINGLE`) to begin with, that's what we have here :-\

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Thanks for warning I read the documentation you are right.It is written that in single-buffered case this function has no effect.

Comment: I found the problem after playing with it all last night. The transformation order was the issue.

glTranslatef(100, 100, 0);
glRotatef(180.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
glScalef(-1.0f,1.0f,1.0f); @Cagkan Toptas